# Python Pyplot - Format Plotted Graph's Y Axis as a Percent to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to represent CDC Delay of Care data as a line graph but am having some trouble formatting the y axis so that it is a percentage to the hundredths place.  I would also like for the x axis to show every year in the range selected.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from isolation import isolate_total_stub, isolate_age_stub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# very simple extraction, drop some columns and check some data
cdc_data = pd.read_csv('CDC_Delay_of_Care_Data.csv')

# separate the categories of delayed care
delay_of_medical_care = cdc_data[cdc_data.PANEL == 'Delay or nonreceipt of needed medical care due to cost']

# isolate the totals stub
total_delay_of_medical_care = isolate_total_stub(delay_of_medical_care)

x_axis = total_delay_of_medical_care.YEAR
y_axis = total_delay_of_medical_care.ESTIMATE
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')

plt.show()
```

The graph that displays looks like this:
[line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NxMv.png)

Excuse me for being a novice, I have been googling for an hour now and instead of continue to search for an answer I thought it would be more productive to ask StackOverflow.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See this.[https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html) To view the target year, try the following. `plt.xlim(min(YEAR),max(YEAR))`

Answer (score 0):

1. To change the format of Y-axis, you can use `set_major_formatter`
2. To change X-axis to date in year format, you will need to use `set_major_locator`, assuming that your date is in `datetime` format
3. To change format of X-axis, you can again use the `set_major_formatter`

I am showing a small example below with dummy data. Hope this works.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdate

estimate = [8, 7.1, 11, 10.6, 8, 8.3]
year = ['2000-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2008-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2020-01-01']
year=pd.to_datetime(year) ## Convert string to datetime

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5)) ## Added so the Years don't overlap on each other
plt.plot(year, estimate)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) ## Makes X-axis label with two decimal points

locator = mdate.YearLocator()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator) ## Changes datetime to years - 1 label per year
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%Y')) ## Shows X-axis in Years
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() ## Rotates X-labels, if you want to use it 
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]